# Import PDF files in AOT?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aot

I have an Enterprise Portal application that was successfully deployed in another environment, but it seems that a lot of content was added through Sharepoint Designer after it was initially deployed, such as PDFs that are displayed on the EP application's page. So they are missing in the new instance.

I don't seee them anywhere in the AOT, so is there anyway to package all those images and PDFs in the AOT so next time I deploy an instance of this application, everything deploys at once ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach files to records in AX but this files will store in the database. There is no way to attach files to the AOT, it is a development tool, can't be used as a data store.

Comment: Yes, turns out the way those PDFs file were deployed was through a mapped network drive to the "Enterprise Portal" library and all pasted at once. Mystery solved!